# trying to understand some basic grunt terminology, entities and relationships

Tags: javascript, build, gruntjs

I'm trying to learn grunt and I'm trying to understand the following entities and relationships in the context of grunt:

- plugins
- tasks
- node_modules

I'm reviewing an existing project with a gruntfile.js. Here's some sample code:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
```

The parent project structure has a node_modules directory with a folder for grunt-contrib-sass. Would the entire grunt-contrib-sass subdir be referred to as a "plugin" or would "plugin" refer to some subset of this directory?

The grunt-contrib-sass directory has a nested node_modules subdirectory. I'm assuming that the nested node_modules subdirectory contains the registered dependencies for grunt-contrib-sass.  Is this correct?

The grunt-contrib-sass directory has a tasks subdirectory with a sass.js file.  This directory has a lib subdirectory with a check.js file.  Is the lib subdirectory used to hold supporting js files for a primary grunt js module/task?

Since sass.js is in the tasks subdirectory I'm assuming that this is considered a "sass task."  Is this correct?  Is this task also referred to as a module?  Or does module refer to its parent node_modules directory?

I'm assuming that the sample code code will import all js modules/tasks from the tasks subdirectory of node_modules\grunt-contrib-sass.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grunt is a module for the Node.js Javascript runtime engine. Therefore, what you see is a mixture of terminologies that are related to Grunt and Node.js.

The `node_modules` folder is the place Node.js modules store their dependencies. If a dependency is stated in the `package.json` file, the node packet manager `npm` will install them in this folder.

Grunt as a convention has a `tasks` folder where the executable code for the Grunt task is provided. The Gruntfile.js in the base folder of your project configures the tasks defined by `grunt.registerTask()` to run. But there does not need to be a task in your project, it can also take advantage of a plugin like `grunt-contrib-sass`, as you have seen.

If Grunt encounters the `grunt.loadNpmTasks('task-module')` command, it will look for a `node_module/task-module/tasks`folder. It will load the .js files there, and if it encounters a command `grunt.registerTask('myTask', function ...)`, registers that task function. It will be executed with the `myTask` entry in the global configuration object defined in the project Gruntfile.js as its parameter.

While it is entirely possible for a plugin to define more than one task, it is obviously good practice to define only one per module. Your project, in contrast, will take advantage of (or define itself) multiple tasks.

If you run the `grunt myTask --verbose` command, you can follow the load process right on the command line.

To resume,

- Grunt **plugins** are Node.js **modules** that are mentioned by a grunt load command and usually have a `tasks` subfolder
- **tasks** are the registered functions (as described in the Grunt API) in the Gruntfile of your project itself or in every file in every subfolder that Grunt will scan.
- `node_modules` is the folder all dependencies of Node.js modules are stored in.